# How to keep food moist for longer?

Tags: food, storage

I sometimes carry food to work (freshly made food e.g. burger or sandwich) but by the time I eat it, it is dry and not edible (unless you are too hungry to eat it anyway), what are ways to keep it moist and fresh so it not soft and not too chewy?

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com also has some information that may be of some help. Search their answers, too. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try using [Aluminium foil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_foil):

[image: food wrapped with Aluminium foil]

Being sealed, the moist should stay inside and leave the original texture and taste for the several hours until you eat it.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah this might fit in new answer, I don't like giving different tips in one answer. :)

Comment: I know some say it's not healthy for aluminum foil to touch the food, but in my experience, it works best for sandwiches.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a ziplock type of plastic bag.

One thing against using a tight wrapper, is that the bread can go soggy from the filling if all the air is expelled from the bag before sealing it.

So you can experiment with how much air you leave in the bag, to find the right compromise between not going dry, and not going soggy.

Alternatively you could also experiment with different sizes of rigid plastic box, if you want to protect the food from getting squashed. Again: not too big and not too small.

Answer (score 3):

A trick that might work for food that needs to keep really moist is to wrap them in a moist dish towel; this is great for keeping moisture, might be too much for your purposes. We use it for a sandwich that doesn't have any crust, so moisture keeping is critical.

Link (in Spanish):
https://laopinionaustral.com.ar/como/como-mantener-frescos-los-sandwiches-de-miga-en-la-heladera-455052.html

Answer (score 3):

**How to keep food moist for longer?**

For years now, I have never bought food at lunchtime, as I have allergies to deal with. Besides, I find it more economical to do so. My job location now even has a lunchroom with frige and coffee maker, so life is better.

But when I was landscaping for over two decades, I kept food fresh in different ways.

- Sandwiches and burgers I used [Saran Wrap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saran_(plastic)) also called cling wrap and plastic wrap. I have never had issues with this.
- Vegetables and meat slices I generally kept in [Ziplock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziploc) bags of one form or another for lunch.
- Sandwiches from places such as Subway will get soggy in Saran Wrap and even in their original wrappings! One of girls on my former crew used to bring all her ingredients for her sandwiches separately: (1.)Bread in Saran Wrap; (2.)Fresh ingredients such as vegetables and meat slices in a [Tupperware](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupperware) container; and (3.) Condiments such such as salt, pepper, mustard, mayonnaise, ketchup is another container for making her sandwiches. She used the condiments saved from eating out at fast food restaurants such as McDonalds. It was amusing to to watch, but it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Invented by accident 89 years ago:

[image]

See also https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/seal: v. 1. to close (something) tightly so that air, liquid, etc., cannot get in or out